# E/SQLiteLog: (10) Failed to do file read, got: 0, amt: 4096, last Errno: 2 a que se debe este error?

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hola realizo una base de datos para un proyecto la cual tiene llaves foráneas, al momento de ejecutar un inserción siempre me sale estos mensaje pero si se realiza la inserción de los elementos sin ningún problema pero me gustaría saber si puede causarme problemas este error que me aparece.

[image: Error E/SQLiteLog: (10) Failed to do file read, got: 0, amt: 4096, last Errno: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Si estas realizando inserción mediante el método `insert()` , este no provoca un error, simplemente obtienes -1 cuando no se realizo por alguna causa la inserción de datos.

Este error especifico

> Failed to do file read, got: 0, amt: 4096, last Errno: 2

Puede ocurrir cuando realizas alguna operación en una tabla la cual tiene una estructura incorrecta, desinstala la aplicación y prueba nuevamente.

Comment: Ya cambie el método de inserción por insertOrThrow para que me regrese una excepción pero igual checare el script de mi bd por que a pesar de que aparece ese error, se realizan las inserciones.